# Using Spinner from String Array:NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-logcat

I am new to Android and don't know much. Please help me with this problem

I have a spinner which goes to another class when an option is selected and then clicked on a button. I have given string arrays in `strings.xml`file.

```
<string-array name="month_arrays">
        <item>2015 June</item>
        <item>2015 July</item>
        <item>2015 August</item>
        <item>2015 September</item>
        <item>2015 October</item>
        <item>2015 November</item>
        <item>2015 December</item>
        <item>2016 January</item>
        <item>2016 February</item>
        <item>2016 March</item>
    </string-array>
```

I have used this in a fragment class and using `getStringArrays()` in ArrayList and then stored it in an ArrayAdapter.

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

public CalendarFragment(){}
TextView t1;
TextView t2;
Spinner spinner1;
Button btnSubmit;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
     t1=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     t2=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "font.otf");
     t1.setTypeface(font); 
     t2.setTypeface(font);


     String[] regionsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month_arrays);
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(regionsArray));
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        spinner1 = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());


        btnSubmit = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "OnClickListener : " + 
                        "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()), // This is Testing if it gets Selected
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

    return rootView;

}
```

}

But I get a NullPointer Exception when I go to this Menu and the app gets Force Close.

LogCat

> 08-09 09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-09 09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728): Process:
>   com.naysotech.smartrajagiri, PID: 1728 08-09 09:14:30.857:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1728): java.lang.NullPointerException 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   com.naysotech.smartrajagiri.CalendarFragment.onCreateView(CalendarFragment.java:58)
>   08-09 09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):   at
>   android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
>   08-09 09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
>   08-09 09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):   at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
>   08-09 09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-09 09:14:30.857:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1728):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-09 09:14:30.857:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1728):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   08-09 09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 08-09
>   09:14:30.857: E/AndroidRuntime(1728):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initiate spinner:

```
spinner1 = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

before you try to set adapter for it:

```
spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```